# VMware VSA vs diskless servers and shared storage

Tags: vmware-esxi, storage

I'm specing a vSphere 5.1 two host setup and I'm questioning whether to use local storage in each server with VMware's VSA or go diskless with a Synology NAS which comes highly recommended.

If we leave cost out of the discussion, what should I consider when choosing either option.

Comment: Do you care about performance?

Comment: Well lets start with why are you "questioning" in the first place? Considering that the option you're normally inclined to pick (whichever that is) is probably the one you're used to supporting in general on other server platforms, what prompted you to question that?

Comment: Yes. I will run ~10-15 VMs ranging from Windows 2012 RDS, AD, linux email server etc. With regards to users we're talking less than 10.

Comment: @DJPon3 because I don't have any experience with the VSA and I'd like to hear what others say before I go with a NAS type solution which seems to be more common.

Answer (score 2):

Go NAS unless you never want to use your shared storage for anything other than VMware.  The Synology offers a number of useful feature that you may want to use outside your VMware environment.  In addition, given the number of users, you probably don't need a cluster that requires multiple storage servers.  If you absolutely have to have 24by7 uptime even if one of your servers fails, then I would think that VSA would work.

We went with Synology and have not been disappointed.